# CRM 2013 on premise: Create sharepoint document location only when user selects on documents button at the record

Tags: sharepoint, location, document, dynamics-crm-2013

At present my plugin creates SharePoint location when Accounts record created, But I want to avoid unnecessary SharePoint location created i.e. site/folder, so only when user clicks on Documents menu (or may be some custom button) the SharePoint location should be created.

Can I do this? if yes, how?

---

With Custom button now I am able to create SharePoint locations. But now requirement is to create it on the navigation item "Documents". I am not able to bind the Click event of the Documents navigation item. if I try with

```
document.getelementbyid(item.getId()).onclick = function () {
    calljsfunction()
    }
```

I get error of

```
There was an error with this field's customized event
Field:window
Event:onload
Error:undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 steps:

1.Write CustomAction that creates the DocumentLocation 
2.Call it from javascript,which executed by CustomCommand in the ribbon

See this post for further information:
https://deepakexploring.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/actions-in-crm-2013/

If you need more explanations add comment..

Comment: Yeah I know that it is possible with custom button in ribbon. But Is there any other way that when user clicks at  Documents at particular record. I don't want user to have extra button. Let me know if it is possible?

Comment: Once you have javascript function you can call it from anywhere, so  you can put documents section inside tab or section, and call the javascript function on TabStateChange event, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334481(v=crm.6).aspx#BKMK_TabTabStateChangeEvent

Comment: I want it on the navigation item "Documents". I am not able to bind the Click event of the Documents navigation item. if I try with document.getelementbyid(item.getId()).onclick = function () {
 calljsfunction()
 }

Comment: You cannot and you shouldn't attach events to navigation , it is not supported and may cause upgrading issues

Comment: Thank you Elisheva for your guidance.